# I want to resize a picture with specific dimension without stretching it

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]I have 3 pictures with different dimensions. I want to decrease the size of these pictures without stretching them. I have used content aware with photoshop but it doesn't work as i have 200X842 dimension which is quite small. Is there any solution to this?

This is the original picture. The result i got from content aware is [image]

Comment: It's hard to tell you much without seeing anything.  Please post an example of the original image, and what you want to do, or what has failed. Content aware scaling doesn't work on all images, and is very much dependent on the image itself.

Comment: i have edited my question

Comment: I've added an answer now. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Content-aware scaling works by using a process called [seam carving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seam_carving), which relies upon being able to compress/stretch some parts of an image while protecting others. For images that have complex backgrounds, automatic seam carving will likely fail, or just not work very well.

To get a better result in Photoshop for an image like your example, which has a lot of detail in the background, you need to create an alpha channel which you can use to protect specific areas of the image when using Content-Aware scaling.

Basically, use the Quick Select tool to roughly select some areas to protect

[image]

Then add an alpha channel in the channels panel by clicking on the Mask button, to save the selection as an Alpha Channel.

[image]

Select the RGB channel, go back to the Layers Panel, *Select > Deselect*. Select the image layer in the layers panel. And do *Edit > Content Aware Scale*

In the tool options along the top, set the Protect drop down to the Alpha channel you made previously

[image]

Now Content-Aware scaling will work nicely

[image]

Once you have achieved the desired aspect ratio, then you can crop the leftover edge, and scale the image to the size you want using *Image > Image Size*. Make sure to engage the aspect ratio lock before entering the new size. Obviously if you are reducing the image size, make sure to also choose the Bicubic Sharper (Reduction) algorithm.

[image]

Comment: i have a problem with filling alpha channel. When ever i fill it with black all the layout turns black. Can you please tell me alittle how to do the fill?

Comment: @AyeshaIsrar Another way instead of filling is to hit the Mask button in the channels panel. I always forget about it. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: i have done all the steps that you have mentioned. But the step of your fill screen shot is different then mine. When i fill it with from the drop down list of content it makes the whole layer black. I dont have any white portions

Comment: Sorry, check the Edit.  Make a selection, open the channels panel, hit the Mask button (Save Selection as Channel).

Comment: Sure, About the invert we can also do it from select and then inverse right? @Billy kerr

Comment: No need for inverse if you use the Mask button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129972/discussion-between-ayesha-israr-and-billy-kerr).

Comment: Careful... those two surgeons in the background are going to start making out `:)` +1